# Class name in Junit Request Sampler disappearing in Jmeter 2.13

Tags: junit, jmeter

When i select any class and testmethod as Junit 4 test case, it disapears as soon as i click something else and a default test case comes up that gives me a null exception,for eg: groovy test case/Selenese Test Case. I require the Groovy Library for my test case. 
This happens only in Jmeter 2.13, but this unchecking thing does not happen in Jmeter 2.11, but i need to use the Backend Listener that is only in Jmeter 2.13.

[Image that shows the selection of the junit testcase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ogml.png)

[Image that shows that the test selected is rechecked by some default groovy test case/Selenese Test case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OjM2.png)

[Screenshot of jmeter using Nightly Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnLML.png)

I need a solution to this, please help me out. Thank you

Comment: @UBIK LOAD PACK, can you please help me out

Comment: could you show your jmeter.log using pastebin ?

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK here is the log file: 
http://pastebin.com/VnbQSrw2

Comment: Hi , any feedback, did you have time to test ? thx

Comment: Hi , I would need a sample test plan, logs and java sample class using junit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are facing a NPE in a process related to undo/redo feature:

- https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v2_13/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/gui/GuiPackage.java#L853

Could you try to remove jmeter-plugins 1.4.0 which is a developer snapshot.
Try without it, and if it works report a bug to jmeter-plugins.org

Then try with jmeter-plugins-1.3.1 which is the stable version, it might work but the bug might also be in it.

I created bug:
- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58795

It is now fixed in nightly build so you will have more informations to provide to jmeter-plugins or jmeter.

To use nightly build:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html

> Download the _bin and _lib files
>
> Unpack the archives into the same directory structure
>
> The other archives are not needed to run JMeter.

Comment: I tried using jmeter-plugins 1.4.0 and jmeter-plugins-1.3.1 but it does not work with either of them. tried using the Nightly Build, the disappearance of the test cases is not happening anymore, but my test case is still not working. There are no errors in the log file. The Same test case worked in Jmeter 2.11. I have added the Screenshot of the Nightly Build Jmeter as "Screenshot of jmeter using Nightly Build".Please have a look into this. Thank you.

Comment: Could you show response tab ? I would also need a sample test plan, logs and java sample class using junit

Comment: it worked with the nightly build. had missed a library. Thanx a lot:)

Comment: Hi, it would be nice if you could: 1/ test without jmeter-plugins the 2.13 version and see if bug occurs , 2/ Test NIghtly build by setting in user.properties undo.history.size=25 and see if issue occur and if it does provide the jmeter.log Thanks in advance

Comment: when i test without  jmeter-plugins in 2.13, same bug takes place.

Comment: How do i set the user.properties?

Comment: Hi, just edit it and add the property : undo.history.size=25

Comment: Hi, i am really not sure how and where do i change the properties.

Comment: could you please help me on this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690957/jmeter-distributed-testing-using-java-code/36695479?noredirect=1#comment61016476_36695479